# How big is this app update?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Is it possible to see the size of the download from the App store when updating an iOS device?

As some users have a limited amount of online data they can use in contracts, It would be useful to know the size of the download. Currently the only way I can find out is if the update is larger than 20mb. This then tells me I have to update over a WiFi network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size is normally the size of the full application. What I do is I open the application info screen and look at the file size. Remember, App Store updates are full versions of the file being downloaded, and the existing one replaced.

There is unfortunately no way to do this quickly, you have to check each application individually from the update screen by tapping on its icon.

As pointed out by @cksum, when finding the app on the iPhone, scroll to the bottom and it will show the size.

[image] [image]

Comment: Ha. No one gets my name right ;)

Comment: @gentmatt Thanks for the edit and updated screenshots. I am at work and my Mac is unusable today.

Comment: @cksum Bleh. It's due to the lack of auto-complete in answer :P

Comment: @Diago No problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not know that the whole app was downloaded again.

Answer (score 1):

If got exactly what you need! If you jailbreak your device, there is an app called [AppStore Update Size](http://www.macstories.net/iphone/cydia-tweak-shows-the-size-of-app-store-updates-on-your-iphone/) from the BigBoss repository, it's free and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to jailbreak to get that info. Simply search the App Store and find your program. Then scroll all the way down to the bottom. It shows that particular info: http://img.ly/images/3684277/full

Comment: I think that's the size of the app, not of the update. No?

Comment: Same thing. Delta updates don't exist. When you update the app, iOS pulls the entire version and simply trashes the old one. And since that info always reflects the latest version, it will always apply to your update (should the developer change something that inflates the size, like Chaos Rings adding another language).

Comment: I see... Thanks for the additional information. With your permission, I would like to edit my answer with your information?

Comment: @chsum Hope you don't mind that I stole your screenshot for my answer.

Comment: @Diago nope. Not at all. You guys are free to use it for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

To see how much space an app update takes in iOS 11, tap the more button and it will show you this:
[image: App Update Info]

Answer (score 0):

When downloading an app, your told how much space is taken over. If you've already downloaded something, but still want to know the space thats being taken over, you can always go to your settings and click on all the lists of your apps. It will show how much mb it takes over.